# Maximal torus in $SO(3)$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, compactness, rotations

I'm asked to prove that any two maximal torus in $SO(3)$ only intersects at the identity. This seems to be a work to find all maximal torus up to the conjugate class. I know that the subgroups $SO(2)$ which correspond to rotation around axis are maximal torus, and I doubt these are the all maximal torus, but I just can't find an argument to get justify this. Any hints on how to get start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. If $g \in \mathrm{SO}(3)$, what are its eigenvalues?
2. If $g, h \in \mathrm{SO}(3)$ commute, how does $g$ interact with the eigenspaces of $h$?